# jasmine testing on external library

Tags: testing, d3.js, jasmine

I am attempting to do some basic testing using jasmine. I use an external library & what I intend to do is spy/mock the method calls on the library object (d3) and make sure appropriate methods are called on d3.

```
        var d3Spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('d3', ['select']);
        spyOn(window, 'd3').andReturn(d3Spy);
        expect(d3Spy.select).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

When 'select' is being called on the object, I get this error.

```
TypeError: Object function () {
spyObj.wasCalled = true;
spyObj.callCount++;
var args = jasmine.util.argsToArray(arguments);
spyObj.mostRecentCall.object = this;
spyObj.mostRecentCall.args = args;
spyObj.argsForCall.push(args);
spyObj.calls.push({object: this, args: args});
return spyObj.plan.apply(this, arguments);
 } has no method 'select'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failure in your code is the following

```
spyOn(window, 'd3').andReturn(d3Spy);
```

This line wil return the spy only when you call `d3()`. So it replace the `d3` object with a function that when its called returns the `{select: jasmine.createSpy()}`. But using d3 you will never call `d3()` cause `select` is a static member of `d3`

So the solution is just to spy on `d3.select'

```
spyOn(d3, 'select')
```

Btw. the problem  with libs like `D3` that use heavy chaining is, that its hard to mock. So the `select` spy in your example has to return the an object which fits the d3 Selections object and so on. So sometimes it would be easier to not mock out everything.

Comment: You just pointed out 'all the issues' I was having. I had reverted from the solution you proposed as things were getting more complicated due to chained method calls. For now, I have stopped spying on all method calls and only spy on method calls that are important & have simple chained method calls.